# Linking md5.h library for HTTP Digest sample implementation

Tags: c, gcc

I am struggling to compile a simple C program from [RFC 2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#page-27). The program is `digtest.c` and it uses `digcalc.c`, another file from the sample implementation. The latter one depends on two files that my compiler doesn't know about:

```
#include <global.h>
#include <md5.h>
```

At first I got this error:

> digcalc.c:5:20: fatal error: global.h: No such file or directory

I resolved that by changing `<global.h>` to `<stddef.h>`, it seems. But I still get this error:

> digcalc.c:7:17: fatal error: md5.h: No such file or directory

Now, md5.h seems to refer to the file found in [libbsd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man3/md5.3bsd.html). So I installed `libbsd-dev` and tried to compile the files like this:

```
gcc digcalc.c digtest.c -o digtest -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lbsd
```

where `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` is the location of libbsd.so and libbsd.a files. However, this does not resolve the last compilation error.

Could anyone point out what am I missing here?

Comment: `fatal error: md5.h: No such file or directory` is a compiler error, not linker one. Where is `md5.h`?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, I don't know. I'm just trying to compile the sample program from the HTTP standard. It provides only three files: `digcalc.h`, `digcalc.c` and `digtest.c`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Had to change `<md5.h>` to `<bsd/md5.h>`, as noted on [libbsd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man3/md5.3bsd.html) page.

So instead of the original headers in `digcalc.c`:

```
#include <global.h>
#include <md5.h>
```

I used:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <bsd/md5.h>
```

Also had to change function `stricmp` to `strcasecmp`, its POSIX equivalent. After that the sample code compiled seamlessly.